# Typescript: How overload function in interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to extends a native javascript type in typescript. This is possible using an interface to declare extended properties.
But how to declare overloaded properties ?

```
interface HTMLElement {
    add:(a:string)=>void; // error: add is duplicate
    add:(a:boolean)=>void;
}

HTMLElement.prototype.add = function (a):void{
    if(typeof a=="string"){

    }
    else if(typeof a=="boolean"){

    }
}

class HTMLElement2 {
    add(a:string):void; // ok
    add(a:boolean):void;
    add(a):void{
        if(typeof a=="string"){

        }
        else if(typeof a=="boolean"){

        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You were close.

```
interface HTMLElement {
    add(a:string): void;
    add(a:boolean): void;
}
```

Tipp: I always look at the implementation from Microsoft in the lib.d.ts file. In this case I typed (with Visual Studio code): document.addEventListener and looked (with ctrl + left click) how Microsoft created the interface.

Comment: I don't know why i didn't tried that. It was obvious.

Comment: @Baud wan't at all obvious to me, I found out by doing `typeof` of a concrete function.

Comment: Sorry, but why it works?

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer requires the implementation to include *all* of the overrides. You can also allow the interface to implement *any* of the overloads:

```
interface HTMLElement {
    add: 
        ((a:string) => void) |
        ((a:boolean) => void);
}

class HTMLElementBool {
    add(a:boolean):void{
        // Assume bool
    }
}

class HTMLElementString {
    add(a:string):void{
        // Assume str
    }
}
```

Comment: What would be the point of this? If you make an instance of one of these and type is as `HTMLElement`, the parameter becomes `a: never`.

Answer (score 0):

For simple scenarios like yours, the [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads:%7E:text=always%20prefer%20parameters%20with%20union%20types%20instead%20of%20overloads%20when%20possible) recommend defining the function parameter as a union of types.

> Always prefer parameters with union types instead of overloads when possible

For example,

```js
interface HTMLElement {
  add(a: string | boolean): void
}
```